# Why do we use spread operator or object.assign

Tags: reactjs

Why do we use/is advided to use immutable approach in changing the state

for example, why do people create a copy of a state before changing

For example

```
this state = {
a: 'apple'
b:'ball'
}
```

and then to change state

```
const copyState = {...this.state} 
copyState.b = bunny 
this.setState({...copyState})
```

like, why not just

```
this.setState({b:bunny})
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in React working with the state is completely functional process. Meaning the state is immutable. And if you would write `this.setState({b: 'bunny'})` and print out `this.state` it would only print out `b: bunny` and not `a: 'apple'` as well.

Also your example can be simplified. Instead of assigning a `copyState` variable to an object, you could write the following:

```
this.setState({
  ...this.state,
  b: 'bunny',
})
```

TLDR;
You cannot add values to the state, it is readonly. You need to reassign the state.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have a form for editing a user. It’s common to create a single change handler to handle changes to all form fields. It may look something like this:

```
updateState(event) {
 const {name, value} = event.target;
 let user = this.state.user; // this is a reference, not a copy...
 user[name] = value; // so this mutates state ?
 return this.setState({user});
}
```

The concern is on line 4. Line 4 actually mutates state because the user variable is a reference to state. React state should be treated as immutable.

Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable.

Why?

- setState batches work behind the scenes. This means a manual state mutation may be overridden when setState is processed.
- If you declare a shouldComponentUpdate method, you can’t use a === equality check inside because the object reference will not change. So the approach above has a potential performance impact as well.

Bottom line: The example above often works okay, but to avoid edge cases, treat state as immutable.

Source: [Handling State in React: Four Immutable Approaches to Consider](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/handling-state-in-react-four-immutable-approaches-to-consider-d1f5c00249d5/#:%7E:text=React%20state%20should%20be%20treated%20as%20immutable.&text=This%20means%20a%20manual%20state,object%20reference%20will%20not%20change.)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is to avoid odd bugs and this leads to components that are hard to optimize.

React components refresh or rerender views based on updates to props and state. setState ensures that components are re-rendered based on changes to state. If we start mutating state directly and then calling setState we might end up missing Component refreshes.

For a detailed understanding you can check out -
https://daveceddia.com/why-not-modify-react-state-directly/